# Mythos skill increases from full study of a tome

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-7e

7th edition Call of Cthulhu rules give two mythos skill increase values for each mythos tome: CMI (initial reading) and CMF (full study). The general principle is clear: you gain a bit of knowledge from a basic skim of the book, and significantly more from a deep dive into the horrible content therein. What is not entirely clear from reading the rules is whether the CMI value is contained *within* (ie. is a subset of) the CMF value.

For example, suppose a tome has CMI +5 and CMF +12. Jim skims through the book and gets +5 to his Mythos skill. When he completes a full study, does he then gain another full 12 points of mythos skill (for a total gain of +17)? Or does he gain an additional 7 points (bringing his *total* points gained from that book to +12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being specifically notified otherwise, it's wise to assume that the CMF is an additional gain (it's what the text says and that's what the "+" in the table implies)

p174 : *"If the reader’s Cthulhu Mythos skill is below the Mythos rating of the book, they gain Cthulhu Mythos points equal to the full study (CMF) number."*

If you need more arguments, you'll find that the sum of CMI+CMF in the 7ed table corresponds pretty much to the total gain that was described in previous editions.
For instance, Al Azif has a gain of 18 percentiles in 6ed, a CMI of 6 and a CMF of 12 in 7ed.

Comment: Both answered so far received are good and conclusive and if I could accept both I would. I’m opting for this one because the rules quotes seems marginally more on-point, and also (and especially) for pointing out the correlation between the combined CMI + CMF and the all-in-one value from earlier editions — which is a compelling argument.

Answer (score 2):

### **The first Full Reading that the investigator undertakes gives the full benefit**

Referencing the 7th ed rulebook, it does not say anything about the initial reading affecting the full readings.

There is even an example given the backs up this point.

> Harvey gets his hands on the Book of Eibon...
>
> **Book of Eibon**: Sanity point loss 2D4. Cthulhu Mythos +3%/+8%, Full study 32 weeks. Mythos rating 33%.
>
> Harvey begins reading the book in his home and then continues while on a long train journey...  Harvey’s player makes the roll and is rewarded with +3% Cthulhu Mythos knowledge (the Cthulhu Mythos Initial—CMI number for the tome) ...
>
> Later he decides to undertake a full study of the Book of Eibon... so he gains the +8% Cthulhu Mythos skill points for a full study (CMF)

Comment: Thanks Destruktor. I had read that example but I didn’t find it entirely unambiguous. ‘…he gains the +8% Cthulhu Mythos skill points for a full study’ *could* be taken to mean ‘…he is taken up to the full +8% gain for that book.’ Not that I’m doubting that you’re right, you understand. I’m just overthinking it.